# What's a good way to save captions for images?

Tags: windows-10, pictures, caption, image-formats

I'm saving an image I found on the web to a file. But - the image also has a caption (or some ALT text) which I also want to keep (and it's different than the image title which I use for the filename).

Other than saving an adjacent text file, what's a good way to save the caption for my image? Right now I'm saving a second text file with the same base name, but I'd rather do something smarter.

Comment: In Windows 7 and up you can save it in the file properties

Comment: And does that have any visibility other than right-clicking a file and looking at Properties | Details | Comments ?

Comment: Yes, In W7 when you highlight a jpeg file it will show properties at the bottom of the explorer window, they are also editable there, it does not do this for all file formats. You may have to enable the details pane, Organize>Layout>tick Details Pane

Comment: @Moab: It seems Windows only shows the title, not comments.

Comment: Depending on file type what it will show.

Comment: @Moab: Doesn't show for JPEG with Windows 10.

Comment: Works for me in W10, did you enable the details pane? Mine is a jpg file but should be the same for jpeg. Png however does not show comments.

Comment: @Moab: No, I didn't. Now I have, and I see the comment. Would you make this an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Open File Explorer and enable the Details Pane, once this is done jpeg and jpg files when highlighted will have a comments section where you can put a label if you wish.

This comment will be save in the properties of the file which means if you copy the file elsewhere it will retain that information.

Not all image formats can have comments, png for example does not a comments section or much else.